# How to connect to router's admin page through a second router?

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have a private network setup of 192.168.1.1
I have connected one of LAN ports of this router to WAN port of a second router that I use for the guest router. the second router has IP Address of 192.168.0.1 for the lan side and 192.168.1.156 is the WAN IP.

When I want to reach my guest router from the LAN side of my private network "192.168.1.1" I am not able to do it. I enabled remote management and the ability to ping the router and the best I could do was to ping "192.168.1.156" from LAN side of my private router's network.

For management reasons, I need to be able to connect to the guest router's interface from any computer located on my private network. How can I allow my first router to reach the admin page of the guest router?

My guest router is Netgear R7000P

please see the network diagram for clarification:

[image]

Comment: *I enabled remote management and the ability to ping the router and the best I could do was to ping "192.168.1.156" from LAN side of my private router's network.* This means that your 2nd router is accessible from your private network (as a precaution look MAC address after the ping in your ARP table and ensure that it is the address of 2nd router's WAN). So the problem is in 2nd router management access permissions settings - adjust them. Try to connect your workstation to 2nd router's WAN directly, p2p, and access its management.

Comment: You should be able to access it via `192.168.1.156`. If this doesn't work, the router's option for remote admin page is still disabled.

Comment: The management is on. I can easily connect to the admin from LAN side of the guest router by going to 192.168.0.1 and the admin page comes up. But I can't get to the admin page from behind the router by typing the WAN IP 192.168.1.156 or its gate way IP (192.168.0.1)

Comment: If I didn't miss anything, your current setup allows guests full access to anything, while guests themselves are protected from your "private" network.

Comment: @DanielB my guests can't reach the private network 192.168.1.1 and resources since they are on the other side of WAN port of the guest router. And I am not looking to allow them to reach anything other than the internet. I just want to be able to manage the guest router from the private side of network 192.168.1.1

Comment: No, they absolutely can. The best evidence is the guest router’s WAN address being in your private network. If you switch around the networks, you will achieve the security you desire and you’ll be able to easily reach the guest router’s management web.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the connection of the second router 192.168.0.1 WAN ip, does that mean you plugged the cable into the wan port? If that's it, you have to put it in a LAN port because it's a client of 192.168.1.1 (in dmz I guess).

Comment: As you see in the diagram, a cable goes from LAN port of the first router to the WAN port of the second router. The first router identifies the second router with IP 192.168.1.156 - which means the second router is one of the devices in first router's network. And the second router's IP gateway for the LAN is 192.168.0.1, so it has it's own DHCP and IP range for the guest network.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can enter the **admin page** from the `192.168.0.x`
network only means that it is accessible.

To access it from `192.168.1.x`, you must enable **Remote Management**.
This gives you the ability to access your router from outside its sub-network
in order to view or change its settings.

The [manual for the Nighthawk R7000P](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R7000P/R7000P_UM_EN.pdf?_ga=2.50993258.279999270.1623266946-574483272.1623266946)
specifies this for "Remote Access" on page 88.

Do this from the `192.168.0.x` network segment:

> **To set up remote management:**
>
> 1. Launch a web browser from a computer or mobile device that is connected to the network.
> 2. Enter `http://www.routerlogin.net` in the address field. A login window opens.
> 3. Enter the router user name and password. The user name is `admin`. The default password is `password`. The user name and password are
>    case-sensitive. The BASIC Home page displays.
> 4. Select **ADVANCED > Advanced Setup > Remote Management**. The Remote Management page displays.
> 5. Select the **Turn Remote Management On** check box.
> 6. In the Allow Remote Access By section, specify the external IP addresses to be allowed to access the router’s remote management.
>    Select one of the following:
>
>    - **Only This Computer**. Allow access from a single IP address on the Internet. Enter the IP address to be allowed access.
>    - **IP Address Range**. Allow access from a range of IP addresses on the Internet. Enter a beginning IP address and an ending IP address to
>      define the allowed range.
>    - **Everyone**. Allow access from any IP address on the Internet.
> 7. Specify the port number for accessing the web management interface. Normal web browser access uses the standard HTTP service port 80. For
>    greater security, enter a custom port number for the remote web
>    management interface. Choose a number from 1024 to 65535, but do not
>    use the number of any common service port.The default is 8443, which
>    is a common alternate for HTTP.
> 8. Click the Apply button. Your settings are saved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still doesn't work. all of these are done, please see my Guest Router's config below:   

https://ibb.co/DYSzNy7
https://ibb.co/GC5HpGv
https://ibb.co/NL722Q4
https://ibb.co/K6x3qVS

Comment: Your last image is too bad quality to see the port number. But assuming it's `80`, you should be able to access the page from the main network using `http://192.168.1.156`, or if it's `8080` then by `http://192.168.1.156:8080`. If this doesn't work, search for a firmware update (from the manufacturer or ISP only).

Comment: unfortunately non of these helped. By the way remote management seems to be for managing your router through the internet using DDNS, Which anyways never worked for me in this router (I enabled it multiple times on other routers) - probably the reasons is that this router is not directly in contact with the modem and is behind another router, but I'm not sure if this prevents DDNS to work.  Does any of these have anything to do with port forwarding? maybe I should do some PF in my routers to allow some connections?

Comment: DDNS is only a way for you to map a name to IP. It doesn't really work for a secondary router and is not connected to your question. Enabling Remote Access as above is how this should be done. Check perhaps for firewall blocking the chosen port in the R7000P. Which port is it?

Comment: it's on port 8443

Comment: It might be blocked by some firewall.